# Is there really no solvent (or any other really) glue for polyethylene terephthalate?

Tags: polymers, solvents, plastics

PVC can be glued well with solvent cement wherein it melts somewhat and then sticks together really well as if it was welded, which is really convenient. But I can't find anything similar online for PET. Some sources say there just isn't.

Is there really no room temperature solvent for PET?

The only thing in my experience that holds PET together is this [glue](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/China-Famous-Factory-401-super-glue_62490043422.html) which still does it quite poorly and doesn't seem to melt it, only adheres to it somewhat.

Comment: PET isn't polyethylene. It is polyethylene terephthalate, a completely different class of polymer. And one with very different "stickiness". Which one was the question about: polyethylene or PET?

Comment: my best choice for that could be a polychloroprene-based glue, a SMP Polymer glue or polyacrylate mix glue.

Comment: A polychloroprene-based glue showed no resistance whatsoever when I disconnected the PET pieces. Can you suggest a specific brand that worked for you perhaps?